# how to load slick-carousel file for specific component

Tags: jquery, slick.js, angular8

so new to angular,

- I Have slick-carousel downloaded in node-module
- Added the path in angular.json file
- when i refresh the page the slider is working(i think the js files are loading properly)
- when i route to another page and come bake to same page slider not working(i think the js are not loaded and the slick.css too is not loading)
- at the main page load or when i refresh the page slick.css is loading fine but when i route to another page and come bak the slick.css file goes missing

home.component.html

```
                <ul class="event-list">
                    <li>
                        <time>
                            <span class="day">21</span>
                            <span class="month">june</span>

                        </time>

                        <div class="info">
                            <h6><b>FAREWELL TO MTECH STUDENTS</b></h6>
                            <h6> Farewell to MTech students More Details
                                    </h6>
                            </div>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="event-list">
                        <li>
                            <time>
              <span class="day">21</span>
              <span class="month">April</span>

            </time>
            </div>

            </section>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).on('ready', function() {

      $(".vertical-center-3").slick({
        dots: true,
        vertical: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed:2000,
        nextArrow: null ,
        prevArrow:null
      });

      $('.center').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 5,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:2000,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });

    });


  }

}
```

this is the component that uses slick-slider i am not familiar with importing the file in .ts and calling the function please help me out

Comment: Try giving that jQuery code in index.html file. U aren't supposed to write jQuery inside components in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ngx useful swiper library it's does'nt have jquery dependency
go to this link for installation documentaion
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-useful-swiper

check demo here

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/

and pass config for the Swiper componet as a object

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use jQuery plugin inside Angular. Better you try to get any angular specific carousel or Still If you want to go with it, Write the jQuery code in your **index.html** file at bottom and include the below line at **main.ts** file.

**main.ts**

```
declare var $: any;
```